# two column layout with skew not fullwidth

Tags: html, css, transform, skew

my three feture-three columns section column maybe skew some degree but my design not 100% match, how it possible? anyone help me plz.

[image]

my example code is here

```
<div class="container feture-three-columns">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="images/feture-image1.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="images/feture-image1.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
        <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="images/feture-image2.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="images/feture-image1.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
       <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="images/feture-image1.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="images/feture-image1.png" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
        <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what am I am wrong in CSS or HTML code please describe me

```
.feture-three-columns {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.feture-three-columns .column {
    width: 33.333333%;
    position: relative;
}
.feture-three-columns .img-wrap {
    transform: rotate(-17deg);
}
.feture-three-columns .column  img {
    display: block;
    width: 119%;
    height: auto;
    transform: rotate(17deg) translateX(-83px);
}
.feture-three-columns .column  img.img-mobile { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `translate: skew`. In the example below, I've added this to your `img-wrap` class and removed the rotation. I've also removed the transforms from the images themselves.

```css
.feture-three-columns {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.feture-three-columns .column {
    width: 33.333333%;
    position: relative;
}
.feture-three-columns .img-wrap {
    transform: skew(-10deg) translateX(-12%);
}
.feture-three-columns .column  img {
    display: block;
    width: 120%;
    height: auto;
}
.feture-three-columns .column  img.img-mobile { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="container feture-three-columns">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
        <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
       <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="img-wrap">
            <img class="img-desktop" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
            <img class="img-mobile" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/da65r8o0n/image/upload/v1529585338/samples/landscapes/beach-boat.jpg" alt="" width="534" height="421" />
        </div>
        <div class="grilles">
           content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for an answer, but it's not perfectly working my first image is showing large and 2nd normal and 3rd is the large showing in my ask.